# MS TEAMS Chatbot: Can I restrict my MS Botframework Chatbot to only work with my MS Teams Tenant ID without requiring additional Authentication

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

## Problem Statement:

We have created a FAQ Chatbot using MS Botframework V4, QnA Maker and LUIS. The Client's Information security team suspects if, anyone gets hold of the **MicrosoftAppId** of the chatbot then, anyone would be able to publish the Chatbot on any other MS Teams Subscription causing a security Threat.

**Condition:** The client is not in favor of adding an extra Authentication prompt where the users would have to login despite being logged in MS Teams

## Query:

Having read the problem statement, could anyone please help me with a technique/Methodology where we can restrict down the ChatBot to be usable only from the Client Organization's MS Teams without any additional authentication Login Prompt to the user to sign-in

*-Thanks in Advance*

Comment: not sure why this got downvoted, I think it's a good question...

Answer (score 2):

Please read my blog post about [how bot communications work](https://hilton.giesenow.com/how-bot-calls-actually-work) to get an understanding of the request-response process. As it explains, although the response *looks* kind of "synchronous" from the bot, it's actually not and is sent via a reply to the Bot Framework services itself. In order to do this, your bot code (dotnet, node, whatever) actually needs TWO things - the app id AND the app password, in order to authenticate itself internally. Without these, no-one can run another bot on your behalf, even on that same id. Note that this is a 'regular' bot scenario, and does NOT require the user to actually Sign In to the bot in any way (that is only required if you want to, for example, access resources on the Graph on the user's behalf, like to fetch a file from SharePoint Online).

Separately, but perhaps related, if someone DID have your app id, they could possibly register an app that would result in more messages coming TO your bot (a kind of "DOS" attack, if you like), but that still wouldn't enable them to 'act as' your bot, as mentioned above. [Update: Note that your bot would still end up *responding* to these messages, as it wouldn't know it wasn't your own Teams app. I'd struggle to understand why someone might want to do that though. No one would be able to develop and host a bot that *impersonated* your bot, however - they would need (a) you app password and (b) to change the registered endpoint where you host your bot, in the Bot Framework].

So, albeit that the App Id alone is not enough, you should of course try to protect it (e.g. KayVault), and all the more so with the app password.

On a separate note, it is *also* possible to restrict your bot to only being used from a single (or restricted set of) tenants. Please see my answer at [MS Teams app manifest file Tenant restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382080/ms-teams-app-manifest-file-tenant-restriction/61383764#61383764).

Comment: Hi Hilton! Thanks! ... It certainly is a good technique. As, I understood from your response  that,  we can use this middleware to restrict the chatbot to work with white listed Tenants.   Otherwise if someone gets hold of the  **MicrosoftAppId**, one can create a manifest and register the Bot to another Teams Tenant.  Hope my understanding is correct.?    Thanks Again

Comment: So that's party right - what I was saying is that you have the option for TWO protections here: (a) you can use this middleware to make sure that no one else (i.e. no other tenants) can somehow USE your bot, but also (b) the built-in protections of appid PLUS app password mean no one else can "register another bot" that mimics / impersonates your bot

Comment: By the way, if the answer helped, be sure to mark it correct + upvote, so it can help others too