# How does Teams know the endpoint of an Azure Bot Service bot when registering it via the AppId/BotId?

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

My bot is deployed to Azure's Bot Service, I enabled the Teams channel and I have successfully connected it to Teams. However, what I don't get is **why** it is working! :-)

When setting up the bot in Teams' "App Studio", the UI looks like the screenshot below.
I don't use "Select from one of my existing bots", because the bot is deployed using a different user account. Instead, I paste just the AppId of the bot, using "Connect to a different bot id":

[image]

My questions are:

- How does Teams know what the endpoint of the bot is? Is it calling a global (?) bot registry somewhere using the ID as a key?
- Why does Teams not need the bot's password (when using the Bot Framework Emulator, app ID **and** password are required)?

  - If I set `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` to non-empty strings in `appsettings.json` and run the bot locally, I **must** provide these credentials when using the Bot Framework Emulator, otherwise a 401 is returned.
  - If the bot is deployed to Azure and I connect Teams to it, I never specify the password (see my screenshot) but **only the app ID**. Still, I can talk to the bot just fine through Teams.
  - If **you** know my app ID, you can use my bot...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Me again :])

Have a look at my blog post on [how bots work](https://hilton.giesenow.com/how-bot-calls-actually-work) 'under the covers' - it will explain how the back and forward works, and how the Bot Framework Services provide this 'glue', so to speak.

Comment: I read that post before asking here - unfortunately, most images are missing and I think the diagrams are an essential part of understanding what's going on.

Comment: oh wow, thanks for spotting that! I added a plugin to the blog recently, and I didn't realise it had broken image embedding. Please retry the link, it should be fine now

Comment: Read your article again. Much better with the images, thanks. However, it doesn't answer my 2nd question, maybe you can explain? I edited my question.

Comment: I"m not totally clear which question is number "2", but I think you mean about the password? If so, Teams is basically routing to the bot framework service, which is where it gets the endpoint to send the message - that's all it needs to do, is send the message to your app/endpoint. YOUR app needs to authenticate with Teams, which is why it needs to have the password in order to send a reply to the user. Not sure if that makes it clearer?

Comment: It's kind of "step 5" in the diagram and in the text in my blog post.

Comment: In terms of "If you know my app ID...", there was actually another question yesterday that tapped into this - see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087524/ms-teams-chatbot-can-i-restrict-my-ms-botframework-chatbot-to-only-work-with-my

Comment: I still don't get it. Here's what I read from your comments and blog post: Assume, I have registered my bot (hosted on Azure using Bot Service) as a Teams app. If I don't add any additional middleware and you get access to my bot's app ID (see screenshot above, where's it's redacted), you can create a manifest for a Teams bot in your Team's tenant and communicate with my bot, and my bot will happily send potentially sensitive data to you? I don't see where the password is required here.

Comment: So, if I managed to get your bot Id, I could create another Teams app that *included* your bot. Messages would get sent to it, and it would reply. However, it would still be *your same bot* - no one could impersonate/hijack your bot without the app secret and without changing the registered endpoint address (where you host your bot) in the Bot Framework. As a result, I can't think of a reason why someone might want to do this, it wouldn't achieve much.

Comment: Let's say, my bot discusses business internal sensitive data, like salaries, risks - you name it. My point is: if you fire up Bot Framework Emulator, you'd need the App ID **and** the password. But using Teams, you could get this information, just with the App ID. This feels wrong to me.

Comment: ah ok, now I understand what perspective your concern is coming from. In that case, see the other answer I referred you to, it included info (middleware) on locking your bot to only responding to a 'whitelist' of tenant Ids - that should cover your concerns

Comment: To be clear, that's a different scenario/concern from, say, I'm a 3rd party and I don't want ANOTHER 3rd party to be able to mimic/impersonate my bot

Comment: Can you explain why I need the password when connecting to my deployed bot via Bot Framework Emulator, but not when using Teams? What's the difference? (Want me to put this into a separate new question?)

Comment: I think it's because Teams is doing this implicitly, behind the scenes, via the Bot Framework. I suspect it's part of what happens when you add the "Teams" channel in the Azure portal (depending on how you set up your bot).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Question 1: 
When webservice is hosted, a messaging endpoint gets generated, which routes through the bot service.
Webservice needs App ID and Password from your bot registration to get connected with.

Answer to Question 2:
Teams enables one to create/register bot in teams for testing purpose and the scope of the bot lies within the teams channel Since it is not a hosted one.

Teams app package with your app manifest, that you will install and App ID provided in it connects the Teams client to your web service, routed through the Bot Service.
Mainly, Teams app relies on App ID(unique Microsoft-generated identifier for app) to connect with your web service but not the password.

If you have registered a bot via the Microsoft Bot Framework,you should already have an ID. Otherwise, you should generate a new ID then reuse it when you add a bot.

Both APP ID and Password would be mandatorily used for certain purposes like authentication.

Comment: "Mainly, Teams app relies on App ID(unique Microsoft-generated identifier for app) to connect with your web service but not the password." - that's exactly the part I struggle with. Let's say, you find out about my bot's app ID. You wouldn't be able to connect to my bot using Bot Framework Emulator, because you don't have the password, but you could create a bot app on your Teams, because there you don't need the password. Then you can communicate with my bot?

Comment: @Krumelur, Team manifest is secure. Providing the App Id that's how teams detect the app configuration. App Id is unique one, manifest don't save password.
You can restrict the usage of bot by others by enabling authentication like SSO and communication with the bot would only be fed when the App ID,Password and messaging endpoint tallies with your bot config.